# I am facing **JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of START_OBJECT token** in Spring Boot project

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I am getting **JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of START_OBJECT token**, with my Spring Boot project, when I am trying to save Pojo class object which is mapped with **One-To-Many relationship** with my another Pojo. I am not sure whether I am sending the right format of JSON in Postman. I am trying to save values of a persistent class that has a Collection element Set defined.

The Parent Pojo class:

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vendor")
public class Vendor {

    @Id
    int vendorId;

    @Column
    String vendorName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Customer.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vendorId")

    Set children;

    public int getVendorId() {
        return vendorId;
    }

    public void setVendorId(int vendorId) {
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
    }

    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendorName;
    }

    public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
    }

    public Set getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

Child Pojo Class:

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GeneratorType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    int customerId;

    @Column
    String customerName;

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Vendor;
import com.example.demo.service.VendorDataSaveService;

@RestController
public class VendorSaveController {

    @Autowired
    private VendorDataSaveService dataSaveService;

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public void saveVendor(@RequestBody Vendor vendor) {
        dataSaveService.saveVendorRecord(vendor);
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Vendor;
import com.example.demo.repository.VendorDataSaveRepository;

@Service
public class VendorDataSaveService {

    @Autowired
    private VendorDataSaveRepository repository;

    public void saveVendorRecord(Vendor vendor) {
        repository.save(vendor);
    }
}
```

Repository class:

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.demo.model.Vendor;

public interface VendorDataSaveRepository extends JpaRepository<Vendor, Integer> {

}
```

The JSON Format I have Sent from Postman:

```
    "vendorId" : 101,
    "vendorName" : "JAIN BOOKS",
    "children" : {
                    "customerId" : 1,
                    "customerName" : "AMIT"
                 }
}
```

I am getting this error message on console:-

> Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of START_OBJECT token
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.model.Vendor["children"])

What do I need to improve?

Comment: The message says it all. children is supposed to be a **collection** of customers. But the JSON contains a single customer object, instead of an array of customers.

Comment: @JBNizet sir, could you please tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: `"children": [ ... ]`. children must be an **array**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, JB Nizet nailed it in a comment. Jackson is telling you that it's trying to deserialize JSON into a `Set` (`java.util.HashSet`), which is a collection, but the JSON for that part of the file is a object `START_OBJECT` instead. It doesn't know how to turn an object into a set, so it's giving up.  The error is at `Vendor["children"]`

Your request contains this for children:

```
"children" : {
    "customerId" : 1,
    "customerName" : "AMIT"
}
```

Since `children` is a collection, if you want a single Child, it should look like this:

```
"children" : [
    {
        "customerId" : 1,
        "customerName" : "AMIT"
    }
]
```

That would be an array of objects in JSON, which would correspond nicely to your `Set` of `Customer`s.

Comment: sir, yes I have resolved that issue, but now I am getting this one: Can not set int field com.example.demo.model.Customer.customerId to java.util.LinkedHashMap. Could you tell me why is that? Sorry for silly question.

Comment: Not from the information I have now -- it sounds like Jackson thinks you're submitting a Map for customerId, but if your customer id line still looks like `"customerId": 1`, it'd be hard to fathom why. Maybe post your updated request JSON?

Comment: What should I send to let Jackson know i am submitting customerId only, and not a Map in customer id value.

Comment: You shouldn't have to tell it anything, if your customer id looks like it does above -- that's why I suggested that maybe you post your updated JSON in case there's something that I'm missing about the request now.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is telling you that you are sending a normal JSON object, not a collection object. Please check in the request where you mapped `Set` inside your entity to ensure it is not an object.

Currently you are sending:

```json
{
    "userName": "XAdmin",
    "userFirstName": "Hom",
    "userLastName": "Cliten",
    "userPassword": "adm@123",
    
    **"role": {
        "roleName": "admin",
        "roleDescription": "admin profile"
    }** 
}
```

Instead of the above request, please send:

```json
{
    "userName": "XAdmin",
    "userFirstName": "Hom",
    "userLastName": "Cliten",
    "userPassword": "adm@123",
    
    **"role": [{
        "roleName": "admin",
        "roleDescription": "admin profile"
    }]**
}
```